# Why is $Ind^G_H(M)=Ind^{G/H}_{\{e\}}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra, group-rings

I was looking at some representation theory notes and found the following statement:

$Ind^G_H(V)=\mathbb{C}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb{C}[H]}V=\mathbb{C}[G/H]\otimes_\mathbb{C} V$.

Now, this makes intuitive sense but I am struggling to see precidely why this works. Moreover, does this still work if we generalise the field $\mathbb{C}$ to some (possibly noncommutative) ring $R$?

Comment: I don't understand your second equality. LHS is a $\Bbb{C}[G]$-module, while RHS is not (or maybe it should ask some explanation). Maybe you are considering them simply as $\Bbb{C}$-vector spaces?

Comment: I am thinking that we must be considering them as vector spaces. It is the only thing that makes sense. Actually, come to think of it I am fairly certain the answer is quite obvious. Once you consider the $G$-action then you have $g(g_i\otimes v)=gg_i\otimes v$. Now, $gg_i=g_jh$ for some $h\in H$ and $g_j\in G\backslash H$.

Comment: Yes, this is true when you view the modules as vector spaces, but not otherwise.

Comment: @PL Surely this would work for free modules as well.

Comment: OK sure, I meant more that it's true when you disregard the group action though; as Crostul noted you can't have anything stronger.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H$ be a subgroup of the finite group $G$, and let $M$ be a $G\times H^{\mathrm{opp}}$-bimodule. Then there is a functor from left $H$-modules to left $G$-modules given by 
$$V\mapsto M\otimes_{\mathbb{C}[H]}V.$$ 
If you take $M=\mathbb{C}[G]$ (with the left $G$-translation and the right $H$-translation), then this is the usual induction functor, which explains the first equality.

The second equality, however, usually does not hold when viewing them as $G$-modules (it holds when $H$ acts on $V$ trivially). For a simple example, consider $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2$, and $H=\mathbb{Z}/2$ is the left component. Take $V=\mathbb{C}[H]$. Then $\mathbb{C}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb{C}[H]}V$ is simply the regular representation $\mathbb{C}[G]$, on which $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2$ acts by
$$(a,b)\colon (c,d)\mapsto (a+c,b+d).$$
But $\mathbb{C}[G/H]\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2]$ with the $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2$-action ($G$ acts on $G/H$ by translations)
$$(a,b)\colon (c,d)\mapsto (b+c,d).$$